# lxml and <wbr> tags

Tags: python, html, lxml, wbr

By default lxml doesn't understsand the wbr tag, used to add word-breaks in long words. It formats it as `<wbr></wbr>` when it should be formatted simply as `<wbr>`, similar to the br tag.

How do I add this behavior to lxml?

Comment: I'm not sure of your application, but could you simply delete the closing tag </wbr>?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually it is not difficult to patch libxml2 (this walkthrough was done on Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.7.3)

First define a test program `wbr_test.py`:

```
from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

wbr_html = """\
<html>
  <head>
    <title>wbr test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  Test for a breakable<wbr>word implemenation change
</body>
</html>
"""

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(wbr_html), parser)

result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),
                         pretty_print=True, method="html")
if result.split() != wbr_html.split(): # split, as we are not interested in whitespace differences
    print(result)
    print("not ok")
else:
    print("OK")
```

Make sure that it fails by running `python wbr_test.py`. It should insert a `<\wbr>` before 
`<\body>`, and print `not ok` at the end.

Download, extract and compile `libxml2`:

```
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
tar xvf libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz 
cd libxml2-2.8.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make -j8  # adjust number to match your number of cores
```

Install, and install python libxml2 bindings:

```
sudo make install
cd to_python_bindings
sudo python setup.py install
```

Test your `wbr_test.py` once more, to make sure it fails with the latest libxml2 version.

First make a copy of `HTMLparser.c` e.g. in `/var/tmp`.

Now edit the the file HTMLparser.c at the toplevel of the libxml2 source. Search for the word `forced` (only one occurrence). You will be at the `<br>` tag definition. Copy the three lines starting with the line you just found. The most appropriate insert point is just before the end (after the definition of `<var>`). To get the final comma right in the table insert the three lines before the one with just `'}'` not the one with `'};'`.

In the newly inserted code Replace `br` with `wbr` and change `DECL clear_attrs` to `NULL` (assuming that a new tag does not have deprecated attributes).

The result should diff with the version in `/var/tmp` ( `diff -u HTMLparser.c /var/tmp`) as follows:

```
@@ -1039,6 +1039,9 @@
 },
 { "var",   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, "instance of a variable or program argument",
DECL html_inline, NULL, DECL html_attrs, NULL, NULL
+},
+{ "wbr",   0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, "possible line break ",
+   EMPTY , NULL , DECL core_attrs, NULL , NULL
 }
 };
```

Make and install:

```
make && sudo make install
```

Test your `wbr_test.py` once more. Should show `OK`

Comment: Very cool! Can you confirm there's no way to get similar results with just runtime configuration?

Comment: A different way to phrase the same question: does libxml2 not allow runtime configuration of that list you've patched?

Comment: I would really wonder if that would be possible with libxml2 without restructuring the source. The definitions are in a static const element table, which does *not* get copied into a more dynamic structure, but is used as is. Adding entries to such a table is not possible from C, hence not from Python.

Comment: Thanks Anthon. That seems pretty authoritative. Do you have any inkling if that kind of restructure would be appreciated, upstream?

Comment: Restructuring might be a little overboard.  HTML is the only XML-like language with tag-specific semantics like this; the problem here is just that HTML5 added more tags, and libxml2 is only aware of HTML4.  Adding the new tags, and a way to specify the version of HTML to use, would surely suffice.

Comment: @eevee: I agree that structuring is overboard. But without it I did not see a way to add tags dynamically, whether from C or Python. I think updating a table in a source every 12 years is ok.

Answer (score 6):

Good news!  This is totally impossible.  HTML tag names are [baked right into `libxml2`](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/libxml2/trunk/HTMLparser.c?view=markup#l473).

And `lxml.html.html5parser` contains a couple severe bugs whose fixes haven't yet made it into a release.

But heck, let's fix them locally and see what happens.

```
>>> lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.html5parser.fromstring('<p>hello<wbr>world!</p>'), encoding=unicode)
u'<html:p xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">hello<html:wbr></html:wbr>world!</html:p>'
```

So close, and yet so far.  The structure is correct, at least.

One more try:

```
>>> lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.html5parser.fromstring('<p>hello<wbr>world!</p>', parser=lxml.html.html5parser.HTMLParser(namespaceHTMLElements=False)), encoding=unicode)
u'<p>hello<wbr></wbr>world!</p>'
```

Welp.

It's not *wrong*, at least.

I think I might go file some bugs against lxml and libxml2.

Answer (score 3):

Since `<wbr>` only exists in HTML5, I suspect the Right Thing to do is use `lxml.html.html5parser`.

Short of that, the list of empty tags is defined in regular Python code, so you could always just monkeypatch it; see [lxml.html.defs.empty_tags](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/defs.py).  Patches are welcome, I'm sure.  :)

Comment: @bukzor: 'br' is also in `special_inline_tags` ... you may need to monkeypatch 'wbr' into that as well.

Comment: You may have to import `defs` first and monkeypatch it before importing anything else in lxml, or other modules will have imported the old values.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, why not use the `replace` method of strings to remove the close tags?

```
>>> t = 'Thisisa<wbr></wbr>test'
>>> t.replace('</wbr>', '')
'Thisisa<wbr>test'
```